# When does $\int_\gamma f(z) \,dz = \int_\gamma f(z)\, \overline{dz}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $f = u + iv = u$ (i.e., $v = 0$).

Then is it correct to assert that

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)\ dt = \int_a^b u(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)\ dt = \int_\gamma f(z)\ \overline{dz} \text{?}
$$

In other words, is $f = u$ the condition for when $\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = \int_\gamma f(z)\ \overline{dz}$?

Comment: would you be satisfied with a measure-theoretic answer... one that relied on the Raydon-Nikodym derivative, for example?

Comment: If I could keep this within the bounds of complex analysis that would be best (I appreciate you asking).  I take it my claim above is false?

Comment: @Squirtle: Now that would be nice to see. Can you give just a rough outline of the answer you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, 
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt,\qquad \int_\gamma f(z)\,\overline{dz} = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\overline{\gamma'(t)}\,dt$$
If $\gamma$ is a horizontal line segment, then $\gamma'$ is real and both integral agree. In all other cases, it would take a weird coincidence for them to be equal. The function $f$ being real valued  does not help. For example, if $f$ is identically equal to $1$, then the first integral is $\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)$ while the second is $\overline{\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)}$.

It is true that when $f$ is real, 
$$
\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\overline{\gamma'(t)}\,dt = \int_a^b \overline{f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)}\,dt = \overline{\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)}\,dt   
$$
that is, the second integral is the conjugate of the first one.